# DataTable Editor with django backend for inline edit

Tags: javascript, django, datatables

I am trying to implement a data table editor with django backend for inline editing.

I am not able to get the updated values in my django views while performing the edit operation in the data table.

I console the data inside the 'preSubmit' method of data table editor and its working fine as I expected.

```
  editor.on( 'preSubmit', function ( e, data, action ) {
        console.log(data)

    }
 )
```

Here is the console output .

```
{action: "edit", data: {19054002: {description: "Orion ChocoPie 560gm"}},
table_name: "rp_p_m"}
```

But the problem is while fetching all the keys in django view I am not getting all the keys as I expect which are

`['action', 'data', 'table_name'].`

Code Inside views.py

```
def product_master(request):
    keys = []
    for key in request.POST:
        keys.append(key)

    print(keys)
```

Instead, I am getting the output like this

```
['action', 'data[19054002][description]', 'table_name']
```

All the nested keys get combined with the key 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still actual you can try https://github.com/VVyacheslav/django-rest-framework-datatables-editor

This project implements seamless integration between Django REST framework, Datatables and Datatables Editor. 
You just need to install it with pip:

```
$ pip install djangorestframework-datatables-editor
```

Make some changes to settings.py and use DatatablesEditorModelViewSet instead ModelViewSet or add EditorModelMixin to your views.

Comment: Links are welcome, but try posting the code from the link in case the link becomes inactive.

Comment: Thank you. But i'm afraid that if the link becomes inactive, my code will become useless... And the code itself will not help in this case.